# Suppress "Failed to save key " warning messages in Log

Tags: symfony, logging, symfony4

Is there any way to suppress these log messages in Symfony 4:

**cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CAgencyController%23about%5D%5B1%5D" '(integer) {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DApp%5CController%5CAgencyController%23about%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /mnt/c/Users/...../vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []**

There are hundredes of them in log (monolog) per each request which is really annoying! I have tried to change permissions to 777 as similar question answers suggested but that does no effect (maybe since I'm on WSL). Also I do not have APC installed.

Comment: my guess would be, that this is really due to the filesystem. have you tried placing it somewhere besides /mnt/?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this? This has been cuasing me issues for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using php 7+? Seems like the file your are accessing in a windows filesystem. touch() will fail with php 5.4 (or 5.3 don't remember) on windows filesystems. Also, try changing your cache files owner, (not just 777) wo they are owned by your webserver user. `sudo chown -R user:usergroup directory/`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using vagrant?

I answered the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824774/how-to-fix-touch-utime-failed-operation-not-permitted-on-saving-cache-with)

I had the same problem.

All you need to do is change the type of the synced_folder to nfs, but that option only works with Mac hosts.

To be able to use it in Windows, you need to install [vagrant-winnfsd](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd)

`$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`

Then change the type of the synchronisation in your Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
end
```

The documentation says that it is also needed to change the type of the network to dhcp, but I didn't need to do that to solve my problem.

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

I hope this helped