# Symfony 4 - Failed to save key...of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I find this error on a web page that runs with Symfony 4.3.2

```
Failed to save key "xxxx" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted
```

but I have no idea where it comes from, so if someone has a little lead, I'm a buyer.
I don't know if it can help but I use ubuntu on windows 10

```
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] php.DEBUG: Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php\",\"line\":696,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"/devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php\",\"line\":124,\"function\":\"dumpFile\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Filesystem\\\\Filesystem\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] php.DEBUG: Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php\",\"line\":202,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"/devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php\",\"line\":126,\"function\":\"chmod\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\Filesystem\\\\Filesystem\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_js_routing_js". {"route":"fos_js_routing_js","route_parameters":{"_route":"fos_js_routing_js","_controller":"fos_js_routing.controller::indexAction","_format":"js"},"request_uri":"http://myProject.local/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData","method":"GET"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:09] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:20] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_js_routing_js". {"route":"fos_js_routing_js","route_parameters":{"_route":"fos_js_routing_js","_controller":"fos_js_routing.controller::indexAction","_format":"js"},"request_uri":"http://myProject.local/js/routing?callback=fos.Router.setData","method":"GET"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DFOS%5CJsRoutingBundle%5CController%5CController%23indexAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_route":"_wdt","_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler::toolbarAction","token":"a0f28c"},"request_uri":"http://myProject.local/_wdt/a0f28c","method":"GET"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%23toolbarAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5BSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%23toolbarAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
[2019-07-26 16:04:21] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "%5B%5BC%5DSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%23toolbarAction%5D%5B1%5D" of type integer: touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DSymfony%5CBundle%5CWebProfilerBundle%5CController%5CProfilerController%23toolbarAction%5D%5B1%5D","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted at /devdir/myProject/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:95)"} []
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824774/how-to-fix-touch-utime-failed-operation-not-permitted-on-saving-cache-with) looks fairly similar

Comment: yes but the answer is not adapted to my case so well, if someone has a relevant solution to bring, it will be welcome!

Comment: Are you using vagrant?

Comment: "I use ubuntu on windows 10" no vagrant here

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I got tired of this behavior under windows, I formatted and I switched to linux, like a real developer:)
the problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happened to use FAT/FAT32 or another file system with severely limited timestamp range, then that warning is to be expected.

Symfony's `FilesystemCommonTrait::write()` method calls `touch()` function with unix timestamp 0 to force expire cached content. Unix timestamp 0 represents 1970-01-01 date. In FAT file system the allowed timestamp range is 1980-01-01 to 2099-12-31, according Wikipedia. So the `touch()` function fails and a warning is issued.

The workaround is to modify the `FilesystemCommonTrait::write()` method, around line 80.

Find lines:

```
if (null !== $expiresAt) {
    touch($this->tmp, $expiresAt);
}
```

Insert before those lines:

```
if (0 === $expiresAt) {
    $expiresAt = time() - 1;
}
```

This should achieve virtually the same result by instantly expiring the cached content, but without using an invalid file system timestamp.

Alternatively, change the file system type.

Answer (score 0):

Today, to avoid having to redo this operation at each installation of this dependency, we can use a very simple trick. It is a simple [patch manager](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches). It applies a patch from a local or remote file to any package required with composer.

Installation:

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

Creation of the patch: (for me in: Patches/filesystemtrait_touch.patch)

```
--- a/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php 2021-11-23 19:51:45.000000000 +0100
+++ b/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php 2021-12-17 09:07:46.428495909 +0100

@@ -108,6 +108,10 @@
             fwrite($h, $data);
             fclose($h);

+            if (0 === $expiresAt) {
+                $expiresAt = time() - 1;
+            }
+
             if (null !== $expiresAt) {
                 touch($this->tmp, $expiresAt);
             }
```

Modify composer json:

```json
 {
  "require": {
    // ...
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "5.4.*"
    },
    "patches": {
      "symfony/cache": {
        "modify the FilesystemCommonTrait": "./Patches/filesystemtrait_touch.patch"
      }
    },
    "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true
  }
}
```

Then you can try to remove the component in `vendor/symfony/cache` and run the update command, the patch will be applied automatically

```sh
root#/data/www/myproject: composer update
Gathering patches for root package.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.4.*"
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Gathering patches for root package.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Installing symfony/cache (v5.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Applying patches for symfony/cache
    ./Patches/filesystemtrait_touch.patch (modify the FilesystemCommonTrait)

Generating autoload files
// ...
```

I hope this little tip will be useful to you